# Why does the AND statement in VB compile to a & operator?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am trying to convert VB.NET code to C#.  I have the following:

```
If IsDataProperty(p) And (p.Name.StartsWith("ref_") = False) Then
 ...
```

If I use a decompiler to see what the C# version looks like, I get this:

```
if (this.IsDataProperty(p) & !p.Name.StartsWith("ref_")) {
...
```

The `AND` operator in VB compiled to `&` C# operator.
Shouldn't the code be with `&&` operator:

```
 if (this.IsDataProperty(p) && !p.Name.StartsWith("ref_")) {
...
```

Logically speaking, in the VB code, if `IsDataProperty(p)` is false, the entire statement will be false.

Comment: And logical operator in VB.NET is equal to && in c#

Comment: "Logically speaking, in the VB code, if IsDataProperty(p) is false, the entire statement will be false" - but will it still evaluate `p.Name.StartsWith("ref_") = False`? I believe it will - whereas `&&` is short-circuiting...

Comment: @MaciejLos: Not in terms of evaluation guarantees / short-circuiting.

Comment: VB6 did not support short-circuiting and when they introduced that in VB.NET they chose to keep the same operator (for source code compatibility) with the same functionality and introduce the AndAlso and OrElse. Very, very confusing.

Comment: @MaciejLos Perhaps you meant to say `AndAlso`, not `And`?  `And` operator in VB is numeric in addition to logical and functions equivalently to C# `&` as is noted in the question, it is *not* equivalent to C# `&&`.

Answer (score 5):

VB.NET has special keywords for short circuiting.

```cs
bool valueAnd = conditionA && conditionB;
bool valueOr = conditionA || conditionB;
```

```vb
Dim valueAnd As Boolean = conditionA AndAlso conditionB
Dim valueOr As Boolean = conditionA OrElse conditionB
```

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent of And in VB.NET really is &. To get C#'s && you should have used "AndAlso" in VB.NET.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/andalso-operator